# Vue TypeError: "Cannot read property 'Bd' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, typeerror

When I want to make "new Vue({...}), i always get this TypeError. Im loading the vue.js script in my Google Chrome Extension, and append it in the `<head>` - Tag. It is successfully loaded. Dont know how to solve this Error

[image: Error when call new Vue(...)]

Here is how i load vue js

[image: Here is how i load vue js]

Answer (score 0):

PS: This is an Chrome Extension for the Google Calendar.

I solved this Issue, by loading the script-Tags for vue.js in the End of my script. 
I am manipulating the DOM to inject a Button in the Google Calendar, and when i load the vue.js script after the DOM-Manipulation, then it works. (i dont know why)

Can anyone explain me the behavior??